# Primeng component calendar have a method for close the pop up calendar manually?

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

Exist method for close pop up of calendar component  of primeng?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this might be an open issue for primeng, as others have noticed that the component cannot be closed except for actually picking a date: https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/2001 and https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/1522.

I haven't used primeng before, but this is what I found on the topic.